# Working of Web Worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I was reading about web workers, and I understood that it runs on a separate thread. One doubt I have is, whether the web worker spawns a new thread for every request sent to it. Example, if I have 2 js files wherein I share a webworker between two. Now when I postmessage from both files to web worker, will two threads be created or a single one ?

Comment: webworker runs on a separate thread of its own. it is given its own event loop. it doesn't matter who or how many times it is called. it will have its own single thread

Answer (score 0):

No, each Worker is a single thread, and they still use the same event loop mechanism as the main execution context; meaning, for example, if your Worker runs into an infinite loop, it will lock up completely and not react to any further messages.